# Number of positive real roots in equation $x^6 - x - 1 =0$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I find the number of positive real roots in the equation $$x^6 - x - 1 =0$$
This question is given in my analysis book and I have no idea how to start

Comment: Try to follow the given hint and show your work here, we will give a look to it. Good work!

Comment: Use the first derivative of the function $f(x)=x^6-x-1$ to see how many changes of sign you have in f(x)... count the changes of sign and there you have the number of roots.

Answer (score 7):

Or (more informally) re-write $x^6-x-1=0$ as $x^6=x+1$ and then graph the functions $y=x^6$ and $y=x+1$.

Answer (score 4):

[Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) is a not very well known, but sometimes surprisingly useful, theorem that helps with this problem.
It says that if a polynomials' coefficients have $n$ sign changes when read from left to right, then the number of positive real roots is $n-2k$ for some integer $k\ge 0$. (That is, it is at most $n$, or if it is less than $n$ it is less by an even number.)

In this case, there is a single sign change, so there must be exactly one positive real root.

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $x$. The equation is equivalent to 
$$x^5 -( 1 + \frac{1}{x})=0$$
LHS strictly increasing on the interval $(0, \infty)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so the equation has a unique solution in $(0, \infty)$. Same for the interval $(-\infty, 0)$.